# How to redirect user after login to the page called by his first name?

Tags: redirect, login

I wonder how to redirect a user after login to the page called by his first name (name used for registration).

Example:  Username or first name is John, after login he should be redirected to website.com/john page.

I tried to combine these 2 examples but without luck.

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'ckc_login_redirect' ); 
function ckc_login_redirect() {
    // Change this to the url to Updates page.
    return home_url( '/Updates' ); 
}
```

&

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
```

Please help PHP newbie :)

Comment: Keep in mind there probably is no chance of having only unique first names. In regard to your example, what if there is a second John?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code in your functions.php:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $url, $user ) {

    global $user;
    if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if( in_array( "administrator", $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            $redirect_to = admin_url();
        } else {
            $redirect_to = site_url( '/' . $user->user_login ); // Or $user->first_name
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: That code works only if user is "John".  What I want to accomplish is to have it work for all users.

Which means, if user is John, redirect to mysite.com/john page,
if user is Mary, redirect to mysite.com/mary page etc..

It should be automatic, and I feel that solution is near, just cannot figure it out myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Just updated the code. It's kinda weird but should work.

Comment: It works it works it works !!! :)  Thank you very much!    Just one small edit if you have time. I am not sure how to do it within this function, this >  IF user is admin dont redirect anywhere or even better, redirect to admin panel

Comment: Just updated the code again.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't see way to contact u, so I posted a comment on your site.  Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
function wpse_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $url, $user ) {
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user ) && !empty( $user->first_name ) ) {
        $redirect_to = site_url( sanitize_title_with_dashes($user->first_name) );
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

But, as like @ialocin said, first names are not unique, so not sure this would be a proper approach in some case. However, other way it's also seems to OK as you are doing this only for the logged-in user, so both john should see their own profile data on same `/john` page.

Comment: This code looks ok visualy, but it dont works, I checked on 2 sites and it shows errors, please check whats the issue.  Yes, thats right, there should be Username instead of First name.    Thanks for your effort.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?

Comment: ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_login_redirect' not found or invalid function name in C:\wamp\www\test\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 199


Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0035 1089024 {main}( ) ..\wp-login.php:0
2 0.2063 26967312 apply_filters( ) ..\wp-login.php:765
3 0.2064 26969096 call_user_func_array ( ) ..\plugin.php:199
Test

Comment: Try with the updated code.